# EF generate result objects for SQL OUTPUT clause

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

What can I do so that EF becomes aware of the `output` clause in SPs and generates the result object accordingly?

```
   INSERT INTO goodtable
   (token,
   ip, long_ip,
  ) OUTPUT INSERTED.*
  VALUES
   (@token,
   @ip, @long_ip,
 );
```

What I currently do to circumvent this is writing a dummy select, generate the objects and the comment out the dummy select leaving the output. This is not a good solution for a long term run.

**Please do not suggest changing the SQL.**

Comment: It would be useful to know what you are doing with the output from OUTPUT

Comment: Documentation says it creates a matching type, even for SPs;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx  but is the sql in the SP isnt quite what yiu expect it may not work... I saw a blog somewhere on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried. when importing the stored procedure into EF,  using function import, to add the `returns a collection of` option.
[image: This is the dialog]

I've never tried it, but can't see a reason for it not to work.